# How can I insert Hebrew text into columns? [SQL 2000]

Tags: php, sql-server-2000, hebrew

I tried to insert Hebrew a text value into a column,
But it changes the value to Gibberish.
An example of that:

> mssql_query ("UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMON = N'בדיקה'");

As you can assume, It changes the value of the column, But the value changed to  `?????` and if I try to do it from Query Analyser it works fine.

My column's collation is `HEBREW_CI_AS`. How can I fix this?

Comment: What are using to insert values when it fails?

Comment: this my php code fail:
mssql_query ("INSERT INTO MEMB_INFO (User, Pass, Name) VALUES ('Joni', '123456', 'גוני דף')");

Comment: Can you provide table definition please. And what is your Db collation?

Comment: i don't know what is table definition, is normal i think... and i don't use in DB collation because I have more tables in this DB with binary, hex and english column. and if i change DB collation to Hebrew_CI_AS is damage in else table :X

Comment: Try this `INSERT INTO MEMB_INFO (User, Pass, Name) VALUES ('Joni', '123456', 'גוני דף' COLLATE HEBREW_CI_AS)`. Do not keep passwords in plain text!!!

Comment: i try this in Query Analyzer and this insert "???????", but when i put 'N' (unicode) where the 'Name' column its work fine. but two ways in php is fail ("??????"). and thank you for password tip but is not my original query, is only for fix the Hebrew!

Comment: You are right, there should be `N` prefix to denote `UNICODE` string. You need make PHP send a `UNICODE` string (UTF-32) to serveer rather than UTF-8 or 16. What PHP function are you using?

Comment: I don't understand what your mean of PHP function, but i using simple connect to sql and query for this. (mssql_connect() and mssql_query().) I need add something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem if someone else has this problem here is my way to fix that:

> 1. Create a new database for this specific table or else tables for your web.
> 2. Set Hebrew_CI_AS as collation (everyone to what he created).
> 3. In your PHP code use mb_convert_encoding() function for SELECT and INSERT.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify collation preperty for the string in the `INSERT` statement you are using. Also the string you are inserting should be of `UNICODE` datatype - use `N` prefix for that.

> INSERT INTO MEMB_INFO (User, Pass, Name) VALUES ('Joni', '123456', N'גוני דף' COLLATE HEBREW_CI_AS)

Check that PHP variable can handle unicode characters. Otherwise it will be PHP that turns your string into question marks.

You may check out [SQL Server drivers for PHP](http://sqlsrvphp.codeplex.com/).
And [Unicode Character Properties](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) from PHP doicumentation.

Some resources on PHP and unicode:

http://www.sitepoint.com/bringing-unicode-to-php-with-portable-utf8/

http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

http://allseeing-i.com/How-to-setup-your-PHP-site-to-use-UTF8

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/16/how-to-set-up-unicode/

http://pageconfig.com/post/portable-utf8

Comment: You can give me example how i do that?

Comment: Sorry, I do not do PHP. I've added some links for your reference.

Comment: Thank you for help! but i not get answer for my problem, i tried everything. But! i change to my column type to nvarchar and is show Chinese letters or something like this, what the column type need to be ?